# how to retrieve values using onchange in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have following two modules. In the following **asset1_inspection** class I have created two tree views. **'msr_insp': fields.one2many('results.measure','insp_msr','Inspection Measure',),**. I will create some measures for each inspection.

After that in **feedback.py** when I select a particular inspection in **'insp_msr1'** I used to get assigned measure for that inspection

**config.py**

```
 class asset1_inspection(osv.Model):
        _name = "asset1.inspection"
        _rec_name="inspection_name"

    MAINTENANCE_SELECTION=[
        ('0','Daily'),
        ('1','Weekly'),
        ('2','Fortnight'),
        ('3','Bi-Monthly'),
        ('4','Quarterly'),
        ('5','Half-Yearly'),
        ('6','Yearly'),
        ('7','Bi-Yearly'),

    ]
    MAINTENANCE_TYPE=[
        ('0', 'Corrective'),
        ('1', 'Preventive'),
        ('2', 'Predictive'),

    ]
    SHOUTDOWN_SELECTION=[
        ('0','YES'),
        ('1','NO'),

    ]
    _columns = {

        'inspection_name':fields.char('Inspection Type',),
        'freq_sel':fields.selection(MAINTENANCE_SELECTION,'Frequency'),

        'shut_down':fields.selection(SHOUTDOWN_SELECTION,'Shout Down'),
        'main_type':fields.selection(MAINTENANCE_TYPE,'Maintenance Type',),
        'insp_id1' : fields.one2many('inspec1.grid','insp_id','BoM',),
        'msr_insp' : fields.one2many('results.measure','insp_msr','Inspection Measure',),


    }

asset1_inspection()

class inspec1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'inspec1.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'insp_name' : fields.char('Part'),
                'insp_code' : fields.char('Code'),
                'insp_quty' : fields.char('Quantity '),
                'insp_uom' : fields.char('UoM'),
                'insp_id': fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Insp Id'),
            }

inspec1_grid()

class results_measure(osv.Model):
    _name = 'results.measure'
    _rec_name='measure'
    _columns = {
            'measure' : fields.char('Inspection Measure'),
            'insp_msr' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Insp Measr'),
        }

results_measure()
**feedback.py**


     from openerp.osv import fields, osv
        from openerp import api

    class feedback_form(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.form'
        _rec_name = 'inspec_type'
        _columns={
            'location' : fields.char('Substation Location'),

            'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result',),
        }





    class feedback_tree(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.tree'
        _columns = {
            'insp_type' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type',),
            'frequency' : fields.char('Frequency'),
            'shutdown' : fields.char('Shout Down'),
            'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Result',),
            'insp_rsltts': fields.many2one('feedback.form','Result Id'),
        }

        def get_inspection(self, cr, uid, ids, inspec_type, context=None):
            val = {}
            if inspec_type:
                for det in self.pool.get('asset1.inspection').browse(cr,uid,inspec_type,context=context):
                        val = {
                            'insp_msr1' : det.measure,
                            #'qty' : det.qty,
                            #'uom' : det.uom,
                            }
            return {'value': val}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the on_change you have to go the your view and then to the field that will be changed.

For example:

```
<field name="my_field" on_change="onchange_method(xx_field_a, xx_field_b)"/>
```

So in the above example this field will call the method "onchange_method" when it's changed. You can also give it parameters that contain the current values on the form. This is how you retrieve those values.

The onchange_method itself is pretty simple:

```
def onchange_method(self, cr, uid, ids, xx_field_a, xx_field_b, context=None):
    return {'value': {'my_field': xx_field_a * xx_field_b}}
```

Here you can see I retrieved xx_field_a and xx_field_b from my form because I passed them as parameters in the on_change in the view.

Comment: Go to the view where you defined your many2one and then add the on_change part from the first example